# How can i refresh my ios app when my ios app get connected to the internet without re-opening the app

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the app which I am developing, I want to start/invoke my app normally when it gets connected to the internet. I am using reachability class to test the internet connection but don't know how to reload the app when my app gets connected to the internet.

Comment: What do you mean with "reload" and "refresh"? Do you mean that the user interface of your (already running) app has to be updated, when there is a connection? Or do you want to launch the app?

Comment: I want to launch the app when it gets connected to the internet otherwise splash screen will be visible to the user

Comment: You want to invoke your app when it is in background and gets internet connection ?

Comment: What I want is if  i have opened the app without any internet connection and in the foreground only it gets connected to the internet  then my app should launch otherwise splash screen will be visible to the user.

Comment: You can add internet connectivity notification in the viewcontrollers which you want to change on connnection with internet

Comment: When your app is opened, it cannot relaunch!?!?! Opening an app is launching.

Answer (score 0):

Actually keep a separate view controller with a image view will full screen. This image view will serve as a splash screen. Until the app connected to the internet.

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:splashViewController];
```

or present the splash view controller after app goes into background. Then app comes into foreground check for network connectivity and dismiss or keep the **splashViewController** based on the result.